# What API would I use to find the circulating supply of Ardor?

Tags: ardor, ignis

Is there a way to use API to find the circulating supply of Ardor or any of the child chain tokens?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `getConstants` returns the `totalAmount` of tokens in each chain - inside the `chainProperties` field.